# Javascript cordova camera picture not uploading to firebase

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, firebase-storage, phonegap

I am trying to upload camera picture from cordova app to firebase storage. It is working fine in webbrowser but not working through cordova. I have searched a lot but not able to find the exact solution.

This is the code i have written:-

```
        onOpenCamera: function(oEvent){
            var oImage = this.getView().byId("profilePicId");
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { 
                quality: 25,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
            });
            function onSuccess(imageURI) {
                //var options = { quality: 100 };
                //plugins.crop(function success (newPath) {
                    oImage.setSrc(imageURI);
                    var sBusyDialog = new BusyDialog({
                        customIcon: "Images/loader.gif",
                        customIconDensityAware: false
                        });
                    sBusyDialog.open();
                    var profileUploadRequest = Firebase.uploadFile('users/'+ Firebase.currentUser().uid + '/Profile.png', imageURI);   
                    profileUploadRequest.then(function(snapshot){
                        sBusyDialog.close();
                        var oProfileUpdate = Firebase.updateProfilePic(snapshot.downloadURL);
                        oProfileUpdate.catch(function(oError){
                            sBusyDialog.close();
                            var message = oError.message;
                            MessageBox.show(message, {
                                title : oError.code,
                                icon : sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.ERROR
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    profileUploadRequest.catch(function(oError){
                        sBusyDialog.close();
                        var message = oError.message;
                        MessageBox.show(message, {
                            title : oError.code,
                            icon : sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.ERROR
                        });
                    });
            /*  }, function fail (error) {
                    MessageToast.show('Failed because: ' + error);
                }, imageURI, options);*/
            }

            function onFail(message) {
                MessageToast.show('Failed because: ' + message);
            }
        },

This is Firebase file:-
        uploadFile: function(path, dataUrl){
            var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
            var profileRef = storageRef.child(path);
            return profileRef.putString(dataUrl, 'data_url');
        },
```

Please check it once.
I have went through all the stackoverflow solutions like creating a blob, using cordova file plugin. I have read in firebase that cordova doesn't support file upload but download works.

Thanks.

Comment: `I have read in firebase that cordova doesn't support file upload` well, that's a problem isn't it, if it's true. `There must be a work around` that's like saying *"I've heard getting your head chopped off will kill you, but there must be some workaround"*

Comment: Okay.. i have seen a lot of answer on stackoverflow. and i am talking about this url where it is mentioned https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/firebase-react-native.html    React Native does not support the File and Blob types, so Firebase Storage uploads will not work in this environment. File downloads do work however.